# Schedule SSIS package using Windows Task Scheduler on Server Machine(Windows Server 2016)

Tags: ssis, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I have SSIS package running fine in my local machine, but when I try to run(using DTExec.exe through command line) on Server Machine it throws error...This is because of encryption of password in the connection string( setting is EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey)..... Can anyone suggest me how can I configure it to enable it to run on different environments/machine and still run it using DTExec.exe ?

Comment: Are you the account running the package on the other machines or is it a different account?

Comment: It's a different account

Answer (score 0):

You have encrypted credentials with your account. For simplicity, the password `Pass@word` becomes `Cnff#jbeq` when you apply the key `Toshniwal11`. That encrypted value, Cnn#jbeq is embedded in the package's XML.

The benefit of using "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" is that encryption/decryption is seamless and automatic. However, there's no way to "transfer" the encryption to another account short of the new account, `ServiceAccount`, opening up the same SSIS package, setting that account as the owner and then verifying the sensitive settings.

You need do one of the following

1. Change the account that executes the package to be your account
2. Change owner of the package to be in line with the service account that will run the packages
3. Change your package protection level from EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey to something else - encrypt with password  will require you to add a password to your dtexec call or DontSaveSensitive and then handle setting sensitive properties at run time. There is no "wrong" way of handling this but there is no shortage of approaches

Deploying to the SQL Server Integration Services Catalog *might* handle the problem. When a package is deployed to the IS catalog, it strips the existing package protection level and sets it to `Server` protection level. You *might* need to configure (right click on the Project in IS Catalog and select Configure) if there was a password or other sensitive material in the connection strings of the package. The internal account will have access to the SQL Server keys to decrypt the sensitive material so yes, storing the packages should solve the problem.

Comment: Can this problem be resolved if we use deployment through SQL Server (Integration Catalogue)....Any Idea ?